# how to observe changes to a static object?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to implement geocoding using Google maps JSON API.

I created a model for the location, and and ObjectController,
the model has the async geocoding logic.

I want the controller to observe changes to the model to reflect the most update data.

I'm trying both with binding and observe and both doesn't work:

```
App.Location = Ember.Object.extend({
    formatted_address: null,
    location: {
        lat: null,
        lng: null
    }
})

App.Location.reopenClass({
    geocoded: Ember.Object.create(),
    geocode: function(address) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=' + address,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            success: function(response) {
                App.Location.geocoded.set('response', response);
            }
        });

        return this.geocoded;
    }
});

App.LocationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    contentBinding: 'App.Location.geocoded',
    testProperty: function() {
        console.log('test');    
    }.property('content'),
    testObserve: function() {
        console.log('test');
    }.observes('App.Location.geocoded')
});
```

EDIT: changing to `observes('App.Location.geocoded.response')`fix the issue. can it also work with binding? is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here when you write `contentBinding: 'App.Location.geocoded'`, the content is updated when App.Location.geocoded change. But in the success handler, you don't change the geocoded object, but just update its response property.

So, if you want to keep the binding with the geocoded object, you can try to do

```
App.Location.set('geocoded', Ember.Object.create({response: response}));
```

in the ajax success handler.

Comment: how do I link between the ObjectController to the Object ?
for ArrayController you can pushObject.. how do you update the content of ObjectController, so anything with binding will update ?

Comment: Euh, contentBinding: 'App.Location.geocoded' and App.Location.set('geocoded', Ember.Object.create({response: response})); should work :s